# toggle b-sidebar with an icon in Vue

Tags: vue.js, toggle, bootstrap-vue

I am having a sidebar using bootstrap-vue. I use 2 icons to toggle this sidebar. When clicking on an icon, I use a `function(){isOpen = !isOpen}` with isOpen initialized to false to toggle the sidebar and change the icon from bars to close and it works great. Inside the sidebar, I have a ul tag and a few li tags with router-link. My problem is that when I use the router-link to another route, the icon still doesn't change because now isOpen is true. How can I make isOpen to false when clicking on a router-link. I think I need to bind the icon to some property of the b-sidebar, but I can't find it. Please help me! Here is a picture of the problem I'm having.

This is still working. The sidebar is opening and the icon changes to close icon
[image]

This is the problem I'm having. I router-link to the About Us screen and the icon is still the close icon. It should have been the bars icon
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `isOpen` is part of the component's `data` object (I assume so, but you didn't provide enough info), you can set `@click` listener on your `li` tags and make a method that will toggle it:
Template:

```
<li @click="closeSidebar">My link</li>
```

Script:

```
...
methods: {
    closeSidebar() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }
}
```